# Box2D Soft Body Wheel in Unity3D

Tags: unity, box2d

I was watching this video made with IForce2D, its about creating soft bodied wheels in box2D.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F-aDMZUVw0c

I wanted help in being able to increase the Radius of the Wheel gradually.

I tried increasing the natural distance of spring joint (Distance Joint) between central body and outer body.
But since outer bodies are connected by revolute joint, which force the outer bodies to not change their positions.

I then changed the Anchor Points of Revolute Joint to match the increase in Radius of Wheel. Now, the outer bodies start moving away from center body towards their natural Distance. But gradually some outer bodies rotate and move away from each other.

Check out this video i made showing what i have done:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-CQHvLBg5TQNlBEZXpRaVc5MDQ/edit?usp=sharing

Note:- I am using Unity3D 4.3.4 with 2D Physics, Gravity is Off.

Any ideas?

Comment: The first thing I"d probably consider is adding a hidden more dense, larger wheel. Expanding the small wheel and then when the time is right (and the small wheel reached the rafius of the big wheel) replacing it with the large wheel.

Comment: Try drawing the joints as well, might help you see what's going on.